# statement "foo is callable" return false (with foo is a function)

Tags: python, callable

```
def foo():
    pass
```

a function is a callable object, so:

```
callable(foo) # return "True"
```

but

```
foo is callable # return "False"
```

So, `callable` in `foo is callable` means?

Comment: `foo is callable` means `are foo and callable same function objects?`, however they are different functions.

Comment: Hrm. I almost wonder if it would be reasonable to mark this a duplicate of the comparable question with folks expecting `foo is Foo` to return true (as opposed to `isinstance(foo, Foo)`; it's certainly the same misunderstanding about `is`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy could you provide a link?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ...wish I could. "is" being a stopword makes it hard to search, even though I'm certain I've seen this one inside the last week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`callable` is a function that tests if its argument can be called. Either because it is a function or because it is an object with a `__call__` method.

`foo is callable` tests if `foo` and `callable` are the same object which they are not.

Comment: when will people understand that you cannot use natural language in python? :)